# Twitter Tweet button with iframe - How can I use the actual page title?

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter

Usually, on twitter tweet button, if I don't specify data-text it take the page title page.
But using iframe? How can I get the page title?

I know I can add `&text=` on th querystring, but If I don't want to specify a different page title, but the one where I am? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript you can specify *document.title* property, e.g.:

```
xMyIframe.src = 'mypage.htm?text=' + document.title
```

Comment: Well, it is not so good! Changing src will load iframe again! So 2 load instead of 1...

Comment: Then you need to create IFrame dynamically. You can do this either via DOM or - the simplest way, replace your

`<iframe src='child.html'></iframe>`  

with

`<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<iframe src='child.html?text=" + document.title + "'></iframe>");
    </script>`